# Kubernetes Pod to run with OpenVPN client sidecar and have functional DNS through the tunnel and in cluster

Tags: kubernetes, dns, openvpn, dnsmasq, sidecar

I attempt to build a Pod that runs a service that requires:

1. cluster-internal services to be resolved and accessed by their FQDN (`*.cluster.local`),
2. while also have an active OpenVPN connection to a remote cluster and have services from this remote cluster to be resolved and accessed by their FQDN (`*.cluster.remote`).

The service container within the Pod without an OpenVPN sidecar can access all services provided an FQDN using the `*.cluster.local` namespace. Here is the `/etc/resolv.conf` in this case:

```
nameserver 169.254.25.10
search default.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

##### When OpenVPN sidecar manages `resolv.conf`

The OpenVPN sidecar is started in the following way:

```
      containers:
        {{- if .Values.vpn.enabled }}
        - name: vpn
          image: "ghcr.io/wfg/openvpn-client"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy | quote }}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: vpn-working-directory
              mountPath: /data/vpn
          env:
            - name: KILL_SWITCH
              value: "off"
            - name: VPN_CONFIG_FILE
              value: connection.conf
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
            capabilities:
              add:
                - "NET_ADMIN"
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 80Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 25m
              memory: 20Mi
        {{- end }}
```

*and* the OpenVPN client configuration contains the following lines:

```
        script-security 2
        up /etc/openvpn/up.sh
        down /etc/openvpn/down.sh
```

Then OpenVPN client will overwrite `resolv.conf` so that it contains the following:

```
nameserver 192.168.255.1
options ndots:5
```

In this case, any service in `*.cluster.remote` is resolved, but no services from `*.cluster.local`. This is expected.

##### When OpenVPN sidecar does not manage `resolv.conf`, but `spec.dnsConfig` is provided

Remove the following lines from the OpenVPN client configuration:

```
        script-security 2
        up /etc/openvpn/up.sh
        down /etc/openvpn/down.sh
```

The `spec.dnsConfig` is provided as:

```
      dnsConfig:
        nameservers:
          - 192.168.255.1
        searches:
          - cluster.remote
```

Then, `resolv.conf` will be the following:

```
nameserver 192.168.255.1
nameserver 169.254.25.10
search default.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local  cluster.remote
options ndots:5
```

This would work for `*.cluster.remote`, but not for anything `*.cluster.local`, because the second nameserver is tried as long as the first times out. I noticed that some folk would get around this limitation by setting up namespace rotation and timeout for 1 second, but this behavior looks very hectic to me, I would not consider this, not even as a workaround. Or maybe I'm missing something. **My first question would be: Could rotation and timeout work in this case?**

My second question would be: is there any way to make `*.cluster.local` and `*.cluster.remote` DNS resolves work reliably from the service container inside the Pod *and* without using something like `dnsmasq`?

My third question would be: if `dnsmasq` is required, how can I configure it, provided, and overwrite `resolv.conf` by also making sure that the Kubernetes-provided nameserver can be anything (`169.254.25.10` in this case).

Best,
Zoltán

Comment: You are making 3 questions in one and giving a bounty for it. Doesn't seem very right to me. Stack is a one question per post community. You are actually reducing the chances for people to help you.

Comment: I could rephrase it to one question I guess: _How to make Kubernetes Pod to run with OpenVPN client sidecar and have functional DNS through the tunnel and in cluster?_ (That is the title of the topic.) I simply laid out my thought process to potentially reveal different possible (or infeasible) solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had rather solved the problem by running a sidecar DNS-server, because:

- it is easier to implement, maintain and understand;
- it works without surprises.

Here is an example pod with `CoreDNS`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: default
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: config-volume
    configMap:
      name: foo-config
      items:
        - key: Corefile
          path: Corefile
  dnsPolicy: None # SIgnals Kubernetes that you want to supply your own DNS - otherwise `/etc/resolv.conf` will be overwritten by Kubernetes and there is then no way to update it.
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
      - 127.0.0.1 # This will set the local Core DNS as the DNS resolver. When `dnsPolicy` is set, `dnsConfig` must be provided.
  containers:
    - name: dns
      image: coredns/coredns
      env:
        - name: LOCAL_DNS
          value: 10.233.0.3 # insert local DNS IP address (see kube-dns service ClusterIp)
        - name: REMOTE_DNS
          value: 192.168.255.1 # insert remote DNS IP address
      args:
        - '-conf'
        - /etc/coredns/Corefile
      volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /etc/coredns
    - name: test
      image: debian:buster
      command:
        - bash
        - -c
        - apt update && apt install -y dnsutils && cat /dev/stdout
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: foo-config
  namespace: default
data:
  Corefile: |
    cluster.local:53 {
      errors
      health
      forward . {$LOCAL_DNS}
      cache 30
    }
    cluster.remote:53 {
      errors
      health
      rewrite stop {
        # rewrite cluster.remote to cluster.local and back
        name suffix cluster.remote cluster.local answer auto
      }
      forward . {$REMOTE_DNS}
      cache 30
    }
```

The `CoreDNS` config above simply forwards `cluster.local` queries to the local service and `cluster.remote` - to the remote one. Using it I was able to resolve `kubernetes` service IP of both clusters:

```
❯ k exec -it -n default foo -c test -- bash
root@foo:/# dig @localhost kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local +short
10.100.0.1
root@foo:/# dig @localhost kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.remote +short
10.43.0.1
```

Update:

Possibly, the following Core DNS configuration is sufficient, in case you require access to the internet as well as `cluster.internal` is provided by Kubernetes itself:

```
.:53 {
  errors
  health
  forward . {$LOCAL_DNS}
  cache 30
}
cluster.remote:53 {
  errors
  health
  forward . {$REMOTE_DNS}
  cache 30
}
```

Comment: Looks good, so you setup `REMOTE_DNS` to be `192.168.255.1` in my case, that is the remote DNS server once the VPN client has made the connection. How would you set up `LOCAL_DNS`? Is it a fix IP on Kubernetes?

Comment: @Dyin Yep, there is a `kube-dns` service in `kube-system` namespace. It's IP is usually tenth in the service IP range (`10.100.0.10` for my `10.100.0.0/16`). You can get it with `kubectl describe svc -n kube-system kube-dns | grep 'IP:'`.

Comment: I patched your answer to better explain things and to fix the missing `dnsConfig`. I made it working. Thank you!

Comment: @Dyin thanks! I just fixed formatting in your snippet and a little bit edited the comment to LOCAL_DNS. The IP of the `kube-dns` service depends on which IP-range was used for Kubernetes services and thus it can vary from cluster to cluster. Therefore, it's best to check it in the `kube-dns` service.

Answer (score -1):

Ad 1.) I am not sure I understand what you mean by namespace rotation (do you mean round-robin domain rotation?), but you could set the timeout to 0, so resolver sends right away dns queries to both name-servers and returns the quicker dns response.

The better idea is to leverage a native kubernetes dns (coredns, kubedns) and just set the forwarding rule there, as per documentation you could add something like this to the coredns/kube-dns configmap in the kube-system:

```
cluster.remote:53 {
        errors
        cache 30
        forward . <remote cluster dns ip>
    }
```

This way you won't need to touch `/etc/resolve.conf` in the pod at all, you just need to ensure kubedns can reach the remote dns server... or configure your application for iterative dns resolution
You can find more details in the official kubernetes documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/ and coredns https://coredns.io/plugins/forward/ .
Of course modifying kubedns/coredns configuration requires you to have admin rights in the cluster.

Comment: I have a problem with _"you just need to ensure `kubedns` can reach the remote DNS server"_. The solution you proposed would update `/etc/resolv.conf` on _each_ Pod, but none of the other Pods and not even `kubedns` has access to the remote cluster, but only the Service Pod in my scenario and only through the VPN side-car.

In addition, I think _"but you could set the timeout to 0, so resolver sends right away DNS queries to both name-servers and returns the quicker DNS response"_ would lead to many many resolve errors because it is essentially a chaos-machine. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, in addition to your pod having access to the 2nd cluster, you would need to ensure that kubedns has access there as well, but when thinking about this right now, imo it would be better to setup dedicated kubedns with appropriate forwarding rules, just for the apps which need to communicate with external cluster. Regarding the timeout set to 0, it can cause a DoS on your dns, so it should not be used in the production system.